# Looking for a special subset of the power set of an infinite set

Tags: set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

Let $A$ be an infinite set. Is it always possible to find a subset $\mathscr C$ of the power set $\mathscr P(A)$ of $A$, which has the same cardinality with $\mathscr P(A)$, and has the following property: If $B,C\in\mathscr C$ and $B\ne C$, then the cardinality of $B\cap C$ is smaller than the cardinality of $A$.

Such subset can be found if $A=\mathbb N$. What if $A$ is uncountable?

Answer (score 2):

I have asked this question on MathOverflow in the past. You can find the question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/99119/7206), and as Andreas Blass points out in his answer, it is consistent that $|A|=\aleph_1$ and there are no $2^{\aleph_1}$ subsets of $A$ that every two distinct sets meet on a countable set.

Comment: If fact it’s consistent that $2^\omega_1$ be arbitrarily large, yet there are no $\omega_4$ subsets of $\omega_1$ whose pairwise intersections are countable, if I’m correctly reading Theorem $5.6$(a,d) of the paper that Andreas cited.